# Consulta MySQL sobre una tabla que devuelve un valor común en dos filas

Tags: mysql, sql

##### Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay varias filas que comparten un `post_id` y luego valores de `facet_name` **edad_minim** y **edad_maxima**.

Necesito sacar los `post_id` que tengan en `facet_name` los valores **edad_minima** y **edad_maxima** que contengan un *valor* dado.

**Por ejemplo:** si tengo el valor **19**, debería obtener el `post_id` **127** y **126** ya que las edades mínima y máxima son **15-30** y **10-20** respectivamente, y el **19** está dentro. Si, por el contrario, pusiera el valor **11**, únicamente me devolvería el `post_id` **126**, ya que el **11** está entre **10-20** pero no entre **15-30**.

No se me ocurre con qué consulta puedo conseguir ese resultado. He probado con `WHERE` que agrupa `OR` y `AND`, pero evidentemente así no podría ser.

Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Comment: Puedes indicar la consulta que has intentando? Por otra parte agrupando por el campo post_id, y comparando en el WHERE el valor de facet_name con el deseado deberías poder conseguirlo.

Comment: Hola , recuerda que es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys: Totalmente de acuerdo, debería haber enviado todas las pruebas que había ido haciendo para partir de mis intentos. Tomo nota para la siguiente y siento el error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecciona los valores mínimos y hazles un JOIN con sus respectivos valores máximos, filtrando el rango con el valor deseado:

```
SELECT tmin.post_id
  FROM tabla tmin
    INNER JOIN tabla tmax
      ON    tmax.post_id = tmin.post_id
        AND tmax.facet_name = 'edad_maxima'
  WHERE tmin.facet_name = 'edad_minima'
    AND 19 between tmin.facet_value and tmax.facet_value
```

Comment: ¡Es perfecto y funciona tal y como necesitaba!
No se me había ocurrido que se puede utilizar el INNER JOIN con una única tabla.  ¡Mil gracias, Sal!